# pytorch recover from RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered without restarting script

Tags: python, pytorch

I suppose everybody who has worked with Pytorch knows the error
`RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered`
to some extend.
I'm generating a lot of data with GPU-Code in my script (200k+ long vectors), so it takes a while.
I'm doing this in batches via a generator as I do not have the memory to store all vectors in my GPU at once. The generator has the following structure:

```
    for i in range(0, len(inputs), batch_size):
        try:
            <generate the vectors>
            yield 1, <the vectors>  # Here it was successful
        except RuntimeError:
            print(f'could not generate vectors {index} to {index + batch_size}')
            yield 0, (i, i+ batch_size)  # Here the input was malformed
```

*I know* that some of the input is malformed to the point that generating vectors from it will fail with a runtime error and that's fine, it's not even 1% of my dataset. I want to get the indices and deal with it later.

**Here's my problem**
Once vector creation fails, the GPU is basically bricked and will respond to all requests with aforementioned error. Validating all input beforehand would be cumbersome and slow. I don't want to do it. I want to roll over all malformed inputs and deal with it later.

**My question is**
How can I recover the GPU from this bricked state as easy and fast as possible? All questions that I have found so far ask about fixing the underlying error, which I do not need to do. I just want to get on with generating vectors from my dataset.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it might be to log your progress through the generated input vectors and restart the process/machine if the GPU gets bricked. If the percentage of malformed inputs are small enough, the cost of resetting the GPU/machine might be negligible. You can have a periodic job which checks if you're done with the job and restarts it if it's not. This is a crude way to approach this problem but it should work.

For example:

```
for i in range(0, len(inputs), batch_size):
    try:
        exist = check_if_current_index_has_succeded_or_failed()
        if exist:
            continue
        else:
            log_current_index()
        <generate the vectors>
        log_success()
        yield 1, <the vectors>  # Here it was successful
    except RuntimeError:
        log_failure()
        print(f'could not generate vectors {index} to {index + batch_size}')
        yield 0, (i, i+ batch_size)  # Here the input was malformed
```

Comment: Hi. Since I was not able to find a better solution to the problem at hand, I ended up doing something similar. My script will save its current status and restart itself at the correct position after running into an error while using the GPU. It's a workaround and no solution, but at least it is working.